# C# - Update textbox on forms created in code

Tags: c#

I have a main form called mainForm - this runs my entire app.
In this form I create other forms like this:

```
......
......

  Form[] formMessage = new Form[10];

  int formNumber = 0;       

  System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCancel;
  System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClose;
  System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTimer;
  System.Windows.Forms.Button btnOK;
  System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
  System.Windows.Forms.Label lblMessage;
  System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
  System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTitle;

......
......
public void CreateForm(Form form2)
   {
       this.btnCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
       this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
       this.lblTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.btnOK = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
       this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
       this.lblMessage = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
       this.lblTitle = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       // 
........
       // 
       // lblTimer
       // 
       this.lblTimer.AutoSize = true;
       this.lblTimer.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
       this.lblTimer.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
       this.lblTimer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 120);
       this.lblTimer.Name = "lblTimer";
       this.lblTimer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 16);
       this.lblTimer.Visible = Show_Timer;
       this.lblTimer.TabIndex = 4;

       form2.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
       form2.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
       form2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
       form2.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 142);
       form2.ControlBox = false;

       form2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
       form2.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
       form2.Controls.Add(this.btnOK);
       form2.Controls.Add(this.lblTimer);
       form2.Controls.Add(this.btnCancel);


       form2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
       form2.Opacity = 0.98;
       form2.ShowInTaskbar = false;
       form2.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
       form2.Tag = formNumber;
       form2.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.MyMessageBox_Paint);       

   }


private void FNeventTrigger(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

   formMessage[formNumber] = new Form();
   CreateForm(formMessage[formNumber]);
   formMessage[formNumber].Show();
   formNumber++;
   if (formNumber == 10)
       formNumber = 0;
}

public void lbl_timer_UpdateText()
{
    this.lblTimer.Text = newText
}
```

I use the FNeventRigger to create my form, and I can have upto 10 of them open at each given time - I use this for showing count down timers.

The problem I have is how do I show the count down timer of each form?
If I use : this.lblTimer.Text = newText, then only the newest form that was opened displays the correct timer.... the other forms lblTimer.Text  stop functioning.

Is there a way to address all the lblTimer.Text on all forms opened on the array?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own form class which defines the Label an a method to update this method.
and then initiate all your forms using this new MyBaseForm

```
public MyBaseForm : Form
{
    private Label lblTimer;
    public MyBaseForm()
    {
        lblTimer = new Label();
        Controls.Add(lblTimer);
    }
    public void UpdateTimerText(string text)
    {
        lblTimer.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail, as I do not understand how to implement this (only been programming for a few weeks.....)

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do is to create a new type of forms which has a label that you can update from outside, this is not supported in the standard Form class, so you need to extend the Form class by inheriting from it, and this is what MyBaseForm class does, so after you create this class, you update your code and use this class instead of the Form class to create your list of forms